# How to Abort Informatica workflow if source file has only header row

Tags: command-line, command, informatica

I have a requirement wherein I am checking if source file which is in CSV format has only header rows i.e. 1 row only then I need to fail the informatica workflow. Informatica is installed in Windows server so only Command task is supported not Unix or bash.
I am using below code to count lines in source file using Command Task in workflow.

for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`type $$outputfile ^| find "" /v /c`)do (
echo line count is %%b> $$count_file.txt
)
)

Here $$outfile and $$count_file paths and filenames are picked from param files.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `ABORT()` function that you can use in expression transformation.
Create a dummy column and put a sorter, aggregator right after the source qualifier. in the aggregator, get a count of all data and then join it back to the main flow. After joiner, put an expression transformation with below condition-

```
IIF( cnt_all > 1, NULL, ABORT( 'Only header exists in the input file! Session will be aborted.'))
```

Whole mapping should look like this --

```
SQ -- EXP(add dummy_col) -->SRT on dummy_col -->AGG on dummy_col, calculate Count(*)->| 
                                       |--------------------------------------------> JNR on dummy_col -->EXP (abort if count <=1) --> existing mapping logic...
```

EDIT :
From command task, you can call `pmcmd abortworkflow` when your condition satisfies. Normal syntax is below -

```
pmcmd abortworkflow -service  service  -user username -password  password  -f  folder workflow
```

Comment: Hi @Koushik Roy . I am looking via command task to achieve the same.